# Show that the closure of $\mathbb{Q}\smallsetminus A$ is $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Call a set $A$ in a topological space discrete $X$ if it has no limit point in $X$. Show that, if $A$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{Q}$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then the closure of $\mathbb{Q}\smallsetminus A$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Take an arbitrary $x\in\Bbb R$. What does it mean that $x\in\overline{\Bbb Q\setminus A}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Bbb Q∖A$ were not dense, then there would be an open set of the form $(s,t)$ in $\Bbb R$ which does not intersect $\Bbb Q∖A$. In other words, $(s,t)\cap\Bbb Q⊆A$. Since $A$ is discrete, so is every subset of $A$. On the other hand, $(s,t)\cap\Bbb Q$ is not discrete, as $t$ is a limit point of that set.

Comment: Yes. I have also done it in the same way...btw thanks for ur answer...